# RequireJS module function not found

Tags: module, requirejs

I have the following Backbone module called router (router.js)

```
define(["app/facilities/messenger"], function (messenger) 
{
    return Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "*hash": "onHashChange"
        },
        onHashChange: function (hash) {
            messenger.publish("navigate", hash);
            console.log("Publish navigate");
        },
        start: function () {
            Backbone.history.start();
        }
    });
});
```

Then I run another module called application (application.js) as follows:

```
define(["app/facilities/contentManager","app/facilities/router"], function (contentManager, router) 
{
    return 
    {
        run: function () {
            contentManager.start();
            router = router || new router();
            router.start();
        }
    }
});
```

And I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'start' (application line 6)

Any ideas why my `router` doesn't have a `start()` function? It's clear to me that it should.

Comment: Try `contentManager()` instead of `contentManager.start`

Comment: Nope. no Joy. I don't think it's line 4, I think it's line 6 that is the problem. In other words, not the contentManager, but the router that is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
router = router || new router();
```

to

```
router = new router();
```

I suspect that because `router` always returns as an object your code never tries to run `new router()` and is trying to call `.start()` on an unintialised object.

If you're trying to avoid calling `new router()` multiple times by using that conditional then perhaps return the already initialised router from your module. That way if it gets called again RequireJS will just return you the initialised router and not another instance.